# Restrict text field only to positive integers in SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift4, ios13

I have a text field that increases the amount with button which contains integer numbers, i don’t want minus numbers, it will start from zero. How can i achive this?

```
 @IBAction func beyazDOWN(_ sender: UIButton) {

    calculateBUTTON.setTitle("=", for: .normal)

    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.700, y: 0.700)
    }, completion: { finish in
        UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations:
            { sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity })
    })

    num3 = Int(field3.text!)!;
    self.field3.text = String(num3 - 1);


}
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: You can write your logic in Button action method. if its less than 0 stop there itself.

Comment: I have added my code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var amount:Int{
    willSet{
      if newValue < 0{
        textfield.text = "0"
      }
    }
}
```

where amount is the value you'll be showing on textfield
like `textfield.text = amount`

In accordance with your code:

```
var num3:Int{
    willSet{
      if newValue < 1{
        beyazDOWN.isEnabled = false
      }
      else{
        beyazDOWN.isEnabled = true 
      } 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
@IBAction func beyazDOWN(_ sender: UIButton) {

    num3 = Int(field3.text!)!; 
    if num3 <= 1{
      return
    }


    calculateBUTTON.setTitle("=", for: .normal)

    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.700, y: 0.700)
    }, completion: { finish in
        UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations:
            { sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity })
    })

    self.field3.text = String(num3 - 1);

}
```

Comment: you can use the above code where amount = num3 - 1 according to your code. You may also check for the same just before the last line of the code you've provided.

Comment: Ok, i will try.

Comment: i can not implement thise code, my default value is 0 (zero) and i can increase it. but it also decrease below zero. i want to disbale the beyazDOWN button whet it is zero lets say. so it can not go below zero.

Comment: use the above code and where the value goes 0, just call  ```` .isEnabled = false ```` . Also, use an else clause and set ````  .isEnabled = true  ```` when the newValue is >= 0

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your need. just use this declaration of num3 var and use the code